# git clone to NFS disk error: fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor

Tags: git, clone, nfs

I have a NFS server and shared a disk(without ssd cached) to few host，When users git clone to this NFS disk form our gitlab，it always got error like that:

```
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (430/430), done.
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor.61 MiB | 453.00 KiB/s     
fatal: index-pack failed
```

If only one man git clone, it will be done, if many peoples git at the same time, will get errors.
This is the config of our NFS server:

```
/data/proj 192.168.1.0/24(rw,no_root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

This is the host mount info:

```
192.168.1.10:/data/proj on /proj type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.2.211,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.10)
```

I try to change the NFS server config like async, but it not work, change .gitconfig setting not work so.
I think the issue is more like in NFS-server config, but I don't know how to solve it, Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem with git on an nfs mount. I had a different error message though:

```
Cloning into 'tileserver-gl'...
remote: Counting objects: 2179, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (813/813), done.
remote: Total 2179 (delta 1357), reused 2179 (delta 1357)
Receiving objects: 100% (2179/2179), 3.04 MiB | 22.72 MiB/s, done.
fatal: premature end of pack file, 83 bytes missing
warning: die() called many times. Recursion error or racy threaded death!
fatal: premature end of pack file, 81 bytes missing
fatal: index-pack failed
```

The fix was actually the exact opposite of Cao Cự Bảo's answer. The solution was adding the `sync` option to the mount options in `/etc/fstab`.

With that added the git clone works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you config NFS server with export file with option "sync".
To fixed it, maybe try it file /etc/exports as below:

```
<<folder share nfs>> <<your network>> (rw,**async**)
```

Example: /home/abc 172.33.32.0/255.255.224.0 (rw,async)

On Nfs Client : remount nfs.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have write acces to the git-repository.

Comment: The person who asked the question said that the problem appears only if several users do `git clone` simultaneously, so   your answer seems irrelevant. Besides, it is only a remark, and as such it should be posted as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: In the question: `If only one man git clone, it will be done, if many peoples git at the same time, will get errors` Write access is not the problem.